# hide a child class of parent id in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a scenario where I have

```
<div id="test">
 <div class = "demo1">
  <p> Demo 1 Title </p>
  <h4> This is Demo1 </h4>
 </div>

 <div class = "demo2">
  <p> Demo 1 Title </p>
  <h4> This is Demo2 </h4>
 </div>

 <div class = "demo3">
 <p> Demo 1 Title </p>
  <h4> This is Demo3 </h4>
 </div>

 <div class = "demo4">
  <p> Demo 1 Title </p>
  <h4> This is Demo4 </h4>
 </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to hide the classes `demo1` and `demo4`, i.e. I want to apply `display:none` to them.

How can that be done. Please suggest.

Comment: `$('.demo1, .demo4').hide();` OR `.demo1, .demo4 {display: none;}`

Comment: Explain more! Why you need to hide them? When?

Comment: What is the purpose ? what problem you are facing ? means what have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Just try,

```
$('.demo1, demo4').hide();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You forgot a `'`!

Answer (score 0):

They have classes so you can target them.

```css
#test .demo1,
#test .demo4 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
 <div class = "demo1">
  <h4> This is Demo1 </h4>
 </div>

 <div class = "demo2">
  <h4> This is Demo2 </h4>
 </div>

 <div class = "demo3">
  <h4> This is Demo3 </h4>
 </div>

 <div class = "demo4">
  <h4> This is Demo4 </h4>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will do the work

```
$(".demo1, .demo4").css("display", "none");
```